# Numerov Method with Time Varying Potential

Tags: differential-equations, time-integration, quantum-mechanics

Is it possible to use the Numerov method to solve the Time Dependent Schrodinger Equation ($\frac{i\partial\Psi(x, y, z, t)}{\partial t} = \nabla^2\Psi(x, y, z, t) + \Psi(x, y, z, t)V(x, y, z, t)$) with a time varying potential $V(x, y, z, t)$? If so, how?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you apply a method for second-order equations to a first-order equation?

Comment: @LutzLehmann It is a second order equation on the spatial axis isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but that is the Laplace operator, not a simple second derivative

Comment: @LutzLehmann I'm not sure I understand how that can change the nature of the problem, can you please explain? We could simplify to the 1 + 1 dimensional case with $\psi(x, t)$ and $V(x, t)$, right? Then it would simplify to be a simple second derivative on the spatial axis?

Comment: Let's start again, what do you think is the Numerov method, compared to the Wikipedia entry or the Hairer-Wanner book? And if it is not obvious, how would it apply to this equation? I believe the Numerov "trick" that leads to the so-named methods would here lead to the Crank-Nicholson scheme (trapezoidal method in temporal direction, second order discretization in space directions), but you may have different sources.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I think the only difference I see with the wikipedia entry is that I am use to seeing it in a matrix form, I was following [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.13140/RG.2.2.13878.01602/1) when I did it in 3D. Could well be in Crank-Nicholson, I have been looking into it and it seems similar too what I have done already just in time. Thats part of what I am unsure of. I have a [question](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/42439/can-the-crank-nicolson-method-be-used-to-solve-the-schrodinger-equation-with-a-t) involving that method as well.