# Do Explicit Methods Always Require an Analytical Solution

Tags: ode, implicit-methods, explicit-methods

Following some comments from [another question](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/42439/can-the-crank-nicolson-method-be-used-to-solve-the-schrodinger-equation-with-a-t?noredirect=1#comment83499_42439) I wanted to ask: does an explicit method always require some sort of analytical function/solution?

Let's take Euler for example. You have a function $f$ which takes $y$ and $t$ and is equal to $y'$. But there is no "generic" or one $f$ as far as I know, you need an analytical solution from your problem. If I am computing velocity, perhaps it is $f(y, t) = y/t = \frac{dy(t)}{dt}$.

Suppose I do not have an analytic solution to a derivative of a particular function (or for a higher-order derivative). Can I not use an explicit method? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Not sure I fully understand the question, but for an ODE $y_t = F(t,y)$ you need the RHS function F. The function F does not have to be analytic, it can be a "black box" that takes numerical values of t and y and returns numerical values of F.

Answer (score 3):

You are confused about ODEs. You think that in order to solve an ODE, you need to know what $f=y'$ is. But it's the other way around: When you try to model something in the real work, you ask "how does a quantity $y(t)$ change with time?" Modeling how this quantity changes with time then gives you the $f$ in
$$
  y'(t) = f(t,y(t)),
$$
and then you can in a next step solve the equation to obtain a function $y(t)$ that represents what $y(t)$ will be in the future.

In other words, to know $f$ you don't need to know $y$. But in order to know $y$, you need to know what $f$ is.

Comment: That is what I mean, $y(t)$ can be a number, but we must have an analytic $f$ which describes how $y$ changes. So if I only know, for example $\psi(x) = \frac{-\hbar}{2m}\frac{d^2\psi}{dx^2} + V(x)\psi$ and I dont know $\frac{d^2\psi}{dx^2}$ I cant use an explicit method, right?

Comment: Oh wait, so if I have the TISE, like above, and I solve $\frac{d^2\psi}{dx^2} = \psi - V(x)\psi$ as long as I have $\psi$ I know the relation! Is that it? If so I feel kinda dumb haha

Comment: With regard too my last comment I tried it out, maybe it works for another solution, like velocity $v' = (dv/dt)$ however Schrodinger equation itself needs to be normalized so that particular solution I typed doesn't really work. Also I forgot E in it. But is my basic understanding correct here do you think?

Comment: No, you still miss the idea. Think about population growth, as an example. Let's say that in every year, 1/80th of all people dies and 1/40th of all people has a child. Then if the number of people at time $t$ is $y(t)$, then the rate of change $y'(t)$ is $-y(t)/80 + y(t)/40$. In other words, you get the ODE $y'(t) = (-1/80+1/40)y(t)$ and the right hand side of your ODE will simply be $f(t,y)=(-1/80+1/40)y(t)$.

Comment: Okay, yes, my bad, I wrote $v' = (dv/dt)$ as a function of $dv/dt$ instead of $v$. But ignoring normalization, is what I said about the Schrodinger equation in the previous comments roughly what I you said? I wrote $\frac{d^s\psi}{dx^2}$ as a function of $\psi$ and $x$ (though it should be a time dependent solution), which I could then take and plug into $\psi_{n+1} = \psi_n + step \cdot (\psi_n \cdot (E - V))$ where the ladder part is $f$ after $\psi_n +$.

In your example you seem to do something similar, you don't take an analytic y then derive it to find $y'(t)$ you write f in terms of y

Comment: roughly what you said*

Comment: @cgbsu I think you need to read through a book on mathematical modeling.

Comment: Perhaps. When I posted this question, I thought that you needed to have an analytic solution for $y(t)$ so you could derive it and get a $y'(t)$ or a higher order derivative/rate of change.

In my current understanding  if you have a specific formula, you can simply re-arrange it to solve for the rate of change, but you don't need an analytic solution for it. For example: the ODE for a spring in gravity (with no forces acting on it): $mx'' + kx = 0$ I can just solve for $\frac{-kx}{m} = x''$, so my $f$ becomes $\frac{-kx}{m}$ and I can simulate the spring using (1/2)

Comment: $x_{n+1} = x_n + (t + \Delta t)(f(x_n, t)) = x_n + (t + \Delta t)\frac{-kx_n}{m}$. I could also have a motivated equation (like the rate of population growth/shrinkage) like you had above.

Even if I may not understand it, what would you say, at this moment, is the fundamental misconception I have? (2/2)

Comment: @cgbsu Like I said, you need to have a bit of background in modeling. It's not about shifting symbols from the left to the right of an equation; it's about where they come from physically.

Comment: Do you mean making specific assumptions with specific parameters and modeling the expected behavior of such? I was writing up a "motivated" example of a mathematical model using a rocket, but I hit "refresh" and its gone. But essentially I said I am going to model thrust, gravitational force, drag force and change in mass for a spherically symmetric rocket with full pitch authority (thrust). And if I wanted too I could do

$f(F_t, t) = dF_{thrust}(M(t), d\theta(t), dt) + dF_{gravity}(t) + dF_{drag}(F_t, t)$
$F(t + dt) = f(F(t), t + dt) + F(t)$
(1/2)

Comment: I did not necessarily move around anything around, rather I may construct my changing factors $dF_{thrust}(M_t, d\theta_t, dt), dF_{gravity}(t), dF_{drag}(F_t, t), M(t)$ (where $d\theta(t)$ is a parameter) and combined them to model the change. I have some parameters ($r$, $d\theta(t)$, $m_{dry}$ $F_{thrust_i}$ $m_{initial}$ $\rho_{atmospheric}$ for example) and assumptions (a spherically symmetric "rocket" with full pitch control and no wind speed in constant atmospheric density) from which I derived a model.

Is this sort of what you mean?
(2/2)

Comment: I did not necessarily move around anything around, or even necessarily rigorously mathematically deduce a result, rather inducted one. A "motivated" equation.*
to model the change (expected change in behavior)*

Comment: I did say "even if I don't understand it" in my last couple comments before this, so if you think I still fundamentally don't understand it I wont bug you further haha